# OneDrive REST API Download file

Tags: wcf, rest, memorystream, onedrive

I'm using the REST API of OneDrive in my WCF Web Service. Everything works well but the Download of a file. I need to get the Stream object of the file downloaded but MemoryStream class gives me an Exception about ReadTimeout and WriteTimeout.
This is the code:

```
.... some code ....
var rClient = new RestClient("https://apis.live.net/v5.0/");
var rRequest = new RestRequest(rootFile.id + "/content", Method.GET);
rRequest.AddParameter("access_token", data.accessToken);
var rResponse = rClient.Execute(rRequest); // THE RESPONSE IS OK
byte[] array = rResponse.RawBytes;
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(array); // PROBLEM HERE!
return stream;
```

So when I create the Stream Object the MemoryStream throw 2 Exception on the fields ReadTimeout and WriteTimeout saying that they are not supported for this stream.
I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Nope, makes no sense.  Without the full stacktrace from the exception your question is unanswerable.  ALWAYS catch the exception and either use the link "copy exception details to the clipboard" on the exception helper dialog OR call ToString() on the exception ***and include that text in your question***.  Exceptions tell you what and where things are going wrong, and often tell you the solution as well.

Comment: Thank you Will! I was wrong about where the exception was thrown

Comment: Add your answer below (pad it out a little with code from the actual point of the exception) and you can select it as correct and close this out (without harming your new account--read up on automatic account question blocks on [meta])

Comment: (sorry, accidentally voted to close--everyone please ignore)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Will in the comment, I discovered that the Exception on ReadTimeout and WriteTimeout was not the real problem. The Exception was thrown by a null object in the caller method, after the code posted above.
Below there is the point where the Exception was thrown: the Current object was null.

```
stream = client.DownloadFile(token);
if (stream != null)
{
    **WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/octet-stream";** //HERE
    return stream;
}
```

I removed the line and everything was fixed